# How do I pass data between Dialogs on Android?

Tags: android, dialog

Im practice with an exercise.In need create dialogs and pass information beetween two dialogs.

Main activity and show dialog1

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b1, b2;
String nombre="";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    instancias();
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog1();
        }

    });

}

private void instancias() {
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);

}


private void showDialog1() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Diálogo 1")
            .setMessage("Bienvenido al examen, ¿Estás seguro de continuar?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    showDialog2();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.dialogo1);

                }
            }).create().show();
}
```

And now i show you the Main activity with dialog 2,the firs and second its implements in the MainActivity.I want to create a dialogo3 with the information of the second (dialog2).

```
private void showDialog2() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Diálogo 2")
            .setView(R.layout.dialogo1)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("CONTINUAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("nombre", nombre);
                    showDialog3(nombre);

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).create().show();
}
```

i share dialog3, i have problems for print the name:

```
 private void showDialog3(final String nombre) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Diálogo 3")
            .setMessage("blabla " + nombre + " bla")
            .setView(R.layout.dialogo1)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("CONTINUAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).create().show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a version of your `showDialog3()` method that takes a `String nombre` argument (assuming the structure for `showDialog3()` is broadly the same as `showDialog2()` and `showDialog1()`):

```
private void showDialog3(String nombre) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: thx u.i really appreciate your help ,now how can i print this string in dialog3.Thanks really

Comment: forgive this its ok.Thx u again

Comment: @Serj Does it work if, instead of passing `nombre` as an argument, you write in a hardcoded `String` (i.e. `showDialog3("Test Name")`)?

Comment: No.It appears "nombre"=nombre, no the argument what i put